# How to send mail from IBM lotus notes using nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, nodemailer

I am trying my hand on sending mail from Lotus notes using Nodemailer, however I'm not sure of the host and port to be used for the same. It's working fine with Gmail SMTP details. 
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If on the Domino server the smtp listener task is enabled and allows connection from your hostname (via configuration document, by default every hostname is allowed), then it is exactly the same as with gmail. Just enter your domino server name as hostname for your SMTP mail.

It depends on the configuration of your domino server if you need credentials (usually not) and on the configuration of any firewall in between domino and your node.js server if it works at all.

Ask your domino administrator, if SMTP is enabled and if you are allowed to send mail over it.

By default every Domino server does not need username / password for smtp authentication and listens to port 25 (as every other default smpt server). 
If authentication is enabled, then only a domino administrator can help you by providing appropriate login name and password, there is no "one fits all" user and password.

The hostname you use for connection is either the fully qualified host name of your domino server or its IP- address.

TO clarify further: To send an SMTP mail you need a Domino server, a Lotus Notes Client is not able to listen for SMTP connections, you will not be able to programmatically send mails over the client using SMTP.

Comment: Are the SMTP details generic for all or specific to someone?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: The SMTP details required to configure lotus notes (host and port) are same for all or specific to a user? From where I can find those if I'm not domino administrator?

Comment: How do you find the Domino server name?

Comment: see my edit... host = hostname of your domino, port = 25 (if admin did not change), user and password = not needed. And: You don't NEED the domino server name as long as you know the hostname or IP of the machine where it runs...